# Isomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}]/(x)\cong\mathbb{Z}/N(x)\mathbb{Z}$
where $x=a+b\sqrt{D},\gcd(a,b)=1$, and $N(x)=a^2-Db^2$. my Idea is to find homomorphism
$$\varphi:\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}]\to\mathbb{Z}/N(x)\mathbb{Z}$$
and to show that
$$\ker(\varphi)=(x)$$

The problem is that I can't find such $\varphi$, hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The norm should be $m:=N(x)=a^2-Db^2$.

First note that there exists one and only one ring homomorphism $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z[\sqrt D]/\langle x\rangle$ whose kernel contains $N(x)$, thus giving rise to a ring homomorphism $\psi:\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z[\sqrt D]/\langle x\rangle$.

Conversely, let $u,v\in\Bbb Z$ such that $av+bu=-1$ and $\varphi:\Bbb Z[X]\to\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ such that $X\mapsto au+Dbv+m\Bbb Z$.
Since $a^2\equiv Db^2\pmod m$ we have $au+Dbv\equiv-a/b\pmod m$, hence $X^2-D$, $a+bX\in\ker\varphi$ hence induces a ring homomorphism $\bar\varphi:\Bbb Z[\sqrt D]/\langle a+b\sqrt D\rangle\to\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$.

Clearly, $\bar\varphi\circ\psi$ is the identity.
Conversely, $\psi\circ\bar\varphi:\sqrt D\mapsto au+Dbv$ and since
$$au+Dbv-\sqrt D=(a+b\sqrt D)(u+v\sqrt D)$$
also $\psi\circ\bar\varphi$ is the identity.